Exclude Substring by IsMatch
I want to exclude file paths that does not match certain conditions like substrings or suffixes in the file name. In the given case the excluded suffix is "ZANG". My c# code:
string dirPath = "C:/path/to/file/";
string fileNamePre = "AnLe";
string regExSuf = @"[A-Z0-9_]*(?!ZANG)\.xml";
Regex rg = new Regex("^" + dirPath + fileNamePre + regExSuf + "$");
string[] fileNames = new[] {"AnLe.xml","AnLe_ZANG.xml","AnLe_TE.xml"};
IEnumerable<string> resultFilePaths = fileNames.Select(element => dirPath + element).Where(element => {
    return rg.IsMatch(element);
});

If element = "C:/path/to/file/AnLe_ZANG.xml", then rg.IsMatch(element) should return false, else true.

Tips: (1) Avoid creating a Regex inside a loop (like this Where()) unless it depends on the loop value. Regex are expensive to create and initialize, and can often be reused without problems. (2) Put the path/file results in an array for us and drop the Directory.GetFiles() so we can easily run your code. (3) This particular case look like it can be done with element => !element.EndsWith("....."), no regex would be needed; faster and more clear.

(1) Thanks, good idea. (2) Done. (3) True, still for future I wonder how to exclude a substring.

Try string regExSuf = @"(?!\w*ZANG)\w*\.xml"; See https://regex101.com/r/vYBqyy/1

Just replace (?!ZANG) with (?<!ZANG). You need a lookbehind, not a lookahead, as .xml will never be equal to ZANG and thus the negative lookahead will always be true and thus redundant.

@WiktorStribiżew This worked greatly!

You should add a single < which makes it a negative lookbehind. That means that the "ZANG not allowed" rule applies to the part that already was matched before where the expression is placed.
In code:
string regExSuf = @"[A-Z0-9_]*(?<!ZANG)\.xml";

Demo fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yYledo
